# How do I specify Arabic text in restructuredtext for sphinx-doc?

Tags: python-sphinx, arabic, restructuredtext, bidi, xelatex

I would like to know the syntax for entering inline Arabic text within an English document so that it produces this output in:

#### .html:

`<span lang="ar" dir="rtl">عربي</span>`

#### .tex (with polyglossia):

`\textarabic{عربي}`

Comment: Docutils FAQ entry: https://docutils.sourceforge.io/FAQ.html#can-i-produce-documents-in-right-to-left-languages

Comment: @mzjn Thanks. I've followed the directions in your link, and I can't get a custom class in my span but I'm not sure how to get dir and lang attributes.

Comment: I don't think there is an obvious way to do that. Perhaps you can "cheat" and use the `raw` role: http://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#raw.